# Javascript animation for fadein value does not change

Tags: javascript, animation

I was trying to make a fade in animation in pure javascript, and I encounter a problem. The opacity does not moove when I make the += 0.1, and I don't know why.

```
function fadeInEffect() {
  var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("target");
  var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
    if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    if (fadeTarget.style.opacity < 1) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity += 0.1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: The main problem is that the opacity is stored as a string. Here's how to solve this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/85uerwn4/ However you can simply use a CSS transition instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicity cast the opacity before you attempt your addition or else it will by default handle the variable type as a string and do a replace instead. Sometimes interpretive languages act a bit inconsistent with auto-type casting so you have to take manual control.

```
function fadeInEffect() {
  var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("target");
  var fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
    if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    if (fadeTarget.style.opacity < 1) {
      fadeTarget.style.opacity = parseFloat(fadeTarget.style.opacity) + 0.1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 100);
}
```